# How to add a transition to text?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a transition to my web page. I want the text in my header to act like the text in the header from the Mineplex site: http://www.mineplex.com/ . I would like to have it where the text becomes "highlighted" from the bottom to the top. I have tried doing it my self, but I have only succeeded in failing. If anyone could help, thanks a lot! Craftd.

**This is my HTML:**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Craftd's Official Website</title>
</head>
<body class="body">
<header class="mainHeader">
<nav><ul>
    <li class="active">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul></nav>
</header>

<div class="mainContent">
    <div class="content">   
            <article class="topcontent">    
                <header>
                    <h2><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to this POST TITLE">Welcome!</a></h2>
                </header>

                <footer>
                    <p class="post-info">Welcome to my Channel!</p>
                </footer>

                <content>
                    <iframe width="580" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oetU4zNP91o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </content>

            </article>

            <article class="bottomcontent"> 
                <header>
                    <h2><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to this POST TITLE">First post</a></h2>
                </header>

                <footer>
                    <p class="post-info"></p>
                </footer>

                <content>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dlior sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dliore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dlior in reprehenderit in vliuptate velit esse cillum dliore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Duis aute irure dlior in reprehenderit in vliuptate velit esse cillum dliore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                </content>

            </article>
    </div>

            <aside class="top-sidebar">
                <article>
                <h2><center>Q & A's!</center></h2>
                <p><ol><h6>
                    <li><i>What is your middle name?</i> Malosi.</li>
                    <li><i>Where do you live?</i> Australia.</li>
                    <li><i>What do you use to record?</i> Fraps, ands sometimes Camtasia.</li>
                    <li><i>What consoles do you play?</i> Just XBox 360.</li>
                    <li><i>What was your first ever game?</i> Mario Bros. on the GameBoy.</li>
                </p></ol></h6>
                </article>
            </aside>

            <aside class="middle-sidebar">
                <article>
                <h2><center>Latest News!</center></h2>
                <p><i><u><center>There are no new stories.</center></u></i></p>
            </article>
            </aside>                

            <aside class="bottom-sidebar">
                <article>
                <h2>Social Networks</h2>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/CraftdMC" target="_blank"><img src="images/Facebook.png" width="64" height="64"></a>
                    <a href="http://www.instagram.com/CraftdMC" target="_blank"><img src="images/Instagram.png" width="64" height="64"></a>
                    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/CraftdMC" target="_blank"><img src="images/Twitter.png" width="64" height="64"></a>
                </article
            </aside>    
</div>

<footer class="mainFooter">
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2014 <a href="http://craftd.com/">Craftd</a></p>
</footer>


    </center>
</body>
```

**This is my CSS**

```
/* ===========================
   ======= Body style ======== 
   =========================== */

body {
    background-image: url('images/image.png');
    color: #000305;
    font-size: 87.5%; /* Base font size: 14px */
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Trebuchet, 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.429;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    }

.body {
    clear: both; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 70%;
}

/* ===========================
   ========= Headings ======== 
   =========================== */
h2 {font-size: 1.571em} /* 22px */
h3 {font-size: 1.429em} /* 20px */
h4 {font-size: 1.286em} /* 18px */
h5 {font-size: 1.143em} /* 16px */
h6 {font-size: 0.95em}  /* 14px */

h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin-bottom: .8em;
}

/* ===========================
   ======= Anchor style ====== 
   =========================== */
a {
    outline: 0;
    }

a img {
    border: 0px; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: #CF5C3F;
    padding: 0 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* ===========================
   ===== Main Navigation ===== 
   =========================== */

.mainHeader nav {
    background: #666;
    font-size: 1.143em;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader nav ul {
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li {
    float: left; 
    display: inline; 
}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 23px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
.mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
    background: #FF9317;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}

.mainHeader nav li a {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader img {
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 3% 0;
}

/* ===========================
   ======= Content Area ====== 
   =========================== */

.mainContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.topcontent {
    background-color: #EBE4DD;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    padding: 3% 5%; 
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.bottomcontent {
    background-color: #EBE4DD;  
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    padding: 3% 5%;
}

.content {
    width: 68%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
}

.post-info {
    font-style: italic;
    color: #919191;
    font-size: 85%;
}

/* ===========================
   ======== Sidebar ========== 
   =========================== */

.top-sidebar {
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #EBE4DD;  
    padding: 2% 3%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.middle-sidebar {
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #EBE4DD;  
    padding: 2% 3%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.bottom-sidebar {
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #EBE4DD;  
    padding: 2% 3%;
}

/* ===========================
   ========= Footer ========== 
   =========================== */

.mainFooter {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    padding-left: 0;
    background-color: #666;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    color: #FFF;    
}

.mainFooter p {
    width: 91%;
    margin: 2% auto;
}

/* ===========================
   ====== Media Queries ====== 
   =========================== */

@media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 780px)
{
    .body {
        clear: both; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        width: 90%;
        font-size: 90%;
    }

    .mainHeader nav {
        background: #666;
        font-size: 1.143em;
        height: 160px;
        line-height: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .mainHeader nav ul {
        list-style: none; 
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .mainHeader nav li {
        margin-left: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
        color: #FFF;
        display: block;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .mainHeader nav a:active,
    .mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
        background: #CF5C3F;
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    .mainHeader nav li a {
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .mainHeader img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 3%;
    }

    .mainContent {
        overflow: hidden;
        line-height: 25px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top: 4%;
        margin-bottom: 2%;
    }

    .topcontent {
        background-color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        padding: 2% 5%;
        margin-bottom: 4%;
    }

    .bottomcontent {
        background-color: #FFF; 
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        padding: 2% 5%;
    }

    .content {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    }   

    .post-info {
        display: none;
    }

    .top-sidebar {
        width: 86%;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        background-color: #FFF; 
        margin-top: 4%;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding: 0 7%;
        margin-bottom: 0;       
    }

    .top-sidebar p {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .middle-sidebar {
        width: 86%;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        background-color: #FFF; 
        margin-top: 4%;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding: 0 7%;
        margin-bottom: 0;   
    }

    .middle-sidebar p {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .bottom-sidebar {
        width: 86%;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        background-color: #FFF; 
        margin-top: 4%;
        margin-left: 0%;
        padding: 0 7%;
        margin-bottom: 1%;
    }

    .bottom-sidebar p {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .mainFooter {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: 2% 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        background-color: #666;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        color: #FFF;    
    }

    .mainFooter p {
        width: 86%;
        margin: 2% auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by animating `repeating-linear-gradient`'s `background-position` on `:hover` this way:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/4cjbdoty/4/)

```
.mainHeader nav li a {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(#666666, #666666 50%, #FF9317 50%, #FF9317 200%);
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.mainHeader nav a:hover {
    background-position: 0px -40px;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url('images/image.png');
    color: #000305;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    /* Base font size: 14px */
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Trebuchet, 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.429;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
a {
    outline: 0;
}
a img {
    border: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #CF5C3F;
    padding: 0 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.mainHeader nav {
    background: #666;
    font-size: 1.143em;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: -40px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 430px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 23px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active, .mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
    color: #fff;
}
.mainHeader nav li a {
    background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(#666666, #666666 41px, #FF9317 41px, #FF9317 82px);
    background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(#666666, #666666 41px, #FF9317 41px, #FF9317 82px);
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(#666666, #666666 41px, #FF9317 41px, #FF9317 82px);
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.mainHeader nav a:hover {
    background-position: 0px -40px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li h1 {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header class="mainHeader">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li> <font face="Space Age"><font color="red"><h1>CRAFTD</h1></font></font>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Is there any way to spread the linear gradients apart so that they don't touch each other?

Comment: @CraftdMC - What do you mean?

Comment: @CraftdMC - Do you mean `margin` between the `li`s?

Comment: @CraftdMC - Just add `margin-left: 5px` and `margin-right: 5px` to `.mainHeader nav ul li`. Demo --------> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/720tfs96/3/). Also edited my answer.

Comment: Yes. Also, when I try and put text in between "Gallery" and "About", [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/4cjbdoty/) happens.

Comment: @CraftdMC - It's beacuse you have to put the new text inside `li` otherwise you are breaking the `ul` element. [Check out the updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/4cjbdoty/1/). Also I've added a new rule at the end for vertically aligning the text.

Comment: @CraftdMC -  [After horizontally centering the `nav`](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/4cjbdoty/4/).

Comment: Is there any way to make the header fixed?

Comment: "_fix the header_" - What is wrong with the header?

Comment: I mean make the header stay in place. @chipChocolate.py

Comment: You don't want it to be in the center? If so, How do you want to position it. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I mean when you scroll down, the header will still be at the top of the screen. @chipChocolate.py

Comment: Oh Okay now I get it. Hold on give me a sec.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS really needs some help... there's a lot of duplication and overlap there. I suggest cleaning that up first, before trying to add something new.

If it helps, here's the CSS that's responsible for the transitions on mineplex.com:

```
#top ul a:nth-child(-n+2):after, #top ul a:nth-child(n+4):after {
   position: absolute;
   content: "";
   width: 100%;
   height: 0%;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: -100;
   background: #63cae3;
   transition: height ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

The :after selector inserts content after the links in the nav bar. The height, width, left, bottom, and background properties are all pretty straightforward. The position and z-index properties put the new content behind the link text and the transition property is what's responsible for the animation. You can read more about that [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) and experiment with it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1).

Comment: Thanks! By "cleaning up", do you mean changing:
the .topsidebar, .middlesidebar and .bottomsidebar to just: 

`.topsidebar, .middlesidebar, .bottom-sidebar {
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #EBE4DD;  
    padding: 2% 3%;
}` 


, etc.?

Comment: I mean things like using the selectors "mainHeader img" twice with virtually the same properties.

Comment: Yes, that looks much better!

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish a hover effect similar to the one you linked, you would use:

```
-webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
```

This adds a nice smoothing effect, and can be used to adjust the div height. This will create the effect that you are looking for.

I pieced together an example JSFiddle project to better show off what I mean. You can find that [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/SplashHero/7ohhm17k/3/)